# Computing mean and standard deviation of binomial variate $X$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$  be binomially distributed with $n = 60$ and $p = 0.4$.

(1) When i randomly generate $60$ numbers, `15 to 30` occur most frequently. Why? that is,  what does $p = 0.4$  indicate?

(2) Now i have to compute mean  and standard deviation of $X$.

i know standard deviation,sd=$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar X)^2$

But i think the formula can't be applied directly here since there is condition that $p = 0.4$.

(3) Does $X$ assume the values $x_i=0,1,\ldots,60$ here?

Answer (score 1):

You should first understand the meaning of what $X$ is, and how $n$ and $p$ are playing their role in $X$. In part (3), you also used $x_i$ which you need to understand the meaning of too.

In (1), you are actually performing the experiment $X$ 60 times. In each experiment of $X$, you are generating observations, which are recorded by $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{60}$. These values of $x_i$ (where $0<i<61$) can take the values $0$ or $1$. $1$ represents a "success" and $0$ represents a "failure". Sum up the $x_i$ and you get your 15 or 30. The values are most common due to the Binomial distribution. $p=0.4$, here means that there is a $0.4$ probability of success (generating $1$) and $0.6$ probability of failure (generating $0$).

From here, I think you can figure out the rest of the problem.